# How to define specific color for Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: html, css, datetimepicker

## Issue

I have two different projects both using bootstrap-datetimepicker. In one project,
[the color is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtVJq.jpg). In the other one, [the color is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esMED.jpg). Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="StartDate">From</label>
  <input required id="StartDate" type="text" placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control input-xlarge mydatetime">
</div>
```

## Code

Here is my code.

```
$('.mydatetime').datetimepicker({
  language:'en',
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss',
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  minuteStep:5,
  pickerPosition: "bottom-right"
});
```

Both projects use exact the same way to use datetimepicker as shown above but show different results. I tried to change css locally by adding the following lines in the css file with no help.

```
.mydatetime {
  background-color: #fff ;
  color: #333 ;
}
```

**Does anyone have idea what might go wrong here?** Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you tell that both projects uses same browser?

Comment: @ibnelaiq Same in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `datetimepicker` dates and months take body default color. SO you have to add below code in your css.

```
.mydatetime td, .mydatetime th {
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The way you mentioned doesn't work, but I added it to body and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color and font-color of datepicker do this.

```
.mydatetime{
   background: #333;
   border: 1px solid #555;
   color: #EEE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-datepicker .ui-widget-content {
  background: #999 none;
}
```